# SELECT queries no longer working in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

All of a sudden, no `SELECT` queries are working any longer in the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin, even simple queries on very small tables (e.g. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 2`). There is no error message, it just says "Loading" without anything happening. When I use erroneous query syntax, there is also the "Loading" message.

Opening stored views works, and the query also works when using the Search tab in phpMyAdmin instead of the SQL tab. There doesn't seem to be an issue with space (also looking at the output of `df`).
`INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries both work.
Running `SELECT` queries from R via RMySQL also works.

**What I tried** after searching the web (I barely know anything about Linux, server setup etc.):

- I restarted mysql, apache, and ubuntu.
- I tried another user (but both users actually have the necessary permissions).
- I deleted all my cookies, site data and cache in Firefox, I restarted Firefox (also in safe mode with add-ons disabled), I tried Chrome and I tried Firefox on another computer.
- I restarted the computer on which I use phpMyAdmin.
- It also still doesn't work when the ubuntu terminal and all instances of R are closed, i.e. seemingly no other process can be blocking the tables.

I didn't change anything regarding the server, database, user permissions etc., so I have no idea what could have caused this.

I thought I should **restart PHP** as well, but `sudo service php5-fpm restart` returned 'php5-fpm: unrecognized service'. The output of `php -v` is 'PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli)'. I tried variations of `php5-fpm` as well. But shouldn't restarting the web server also restart PHP anyway? I thought that `sudo service --status-all` should list a PHP service, but there seems to be none.
Running `service php5-fpm start` instead of `restart` also returns 'php5-fpm: unrecognized service'. Might there be a problem with PHP on the server?

---

Database server

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server type: MySQL
- Server version: 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 - (Ubuntu)
- Protocol version: 10

Web server

- Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.46
- PHP extension: mysqli

Comment: Hi ASK,

Could you please share the fix.

Comment: Hi Qmr, I'm afraid I don't have a fix and I'm still interested in ideas on what might have caused this behaviour and how to fix it. In my case, after weeks and weeks, the queries suddenly started working again without me having changed anything (knowingly). It's a mystery to me.

Answer (score -1):

You can check action sql or you can reset to PC

Comment: I don't understand what that means, could you please elaborate?

Comment: i think your sql is having problems , so you need to restart the PC

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by 'check action sql'. The database is on a Linux server, which I already restarted (and the computer on which I have the issue with phpMyAdmin I also already restarted multiple times).